# How to create custom tab size?

Tags: android, android-layout

Like on the following screen. It looks less than standard size. And without vertical lines between icons.

[image: screen]

Comment: OK, I think I would go with standard `TabHost`. If I use tabs with empty labels and define `android:layout_height="45dp"` for `TabWidget`, is there any disadvantage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely not a tab control at all. You can simply use `Buttons` or even better styled `RadioButtons` for pseudo tabs and then use [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) to display sequence of cards based on which button was clicked

Comment: if I place 4 buttons at the bottom, what is the best way to create black background? Should I use ImageView with black image?

Comment: You have to be careful here since simply setting background to black will kill any states you may want to have on your buttons. I would use 4 customized radio buttons placed into RadioGroup (which extends LinearLayout) and see how modifying background of that affects overall look and feel. Also just as a side note - you are trying replicate iPhone design here which may not be ideal